Angular APP_INITIALIZER in library is not called
I had an angular application with APP_INITIALIZER in app.module.ts, where I loaded from a REST API all lists that I use in the combo-boxes, and that worked fine. I moved all my components to a library, and also the APP_INITIALIZER to the library, but now APP_INITIALIZER does not get called.
In the library's module I use APP_INITIALIZER as follows:
function initializeApp(generalService: AbstractGeneralService) {
    console.log("initializeApp");
    return () => generalService.init();
}
const InitProvider = { provide: APP_INITIALIZER, useFactory: initializeApp, deps: [GeneralService], multi: true, }

However, "initializeApp" is never logged in the console.
How can I make APP_INITIALIZER to be called in an angular library?
The project structure is as shown here:

uni-rules-lib.module.ts where the APP_INITIALIZER is used:
import { APP_INITIALIZER, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import {
    DxDataGridModule,
    DxButtonModule,
    DxSelectBoxModule,
    DxTemplateModule,
    DxDateBoxModule,
    DxTreeListModule,
    DxListModule,
    DxTextBoxModule,
    DxFormModule,
    DxTextAreaModule,
    DxCheckBoxModule,
    DxFileUploaderModule,
    DxNumberBoxModule,
    DxPopupModule,
    DxTagBoxModule,
    DxPieChartModule,
    DxChartModule
} from 'devextreme-angular';

import { UniRulesLibComponent } from './uni-rules-lib.component';
import { CboCorrespodentDynamicComponent } from './components/payments/cbo-correspondent.component';
import { AbstractRuleService } from './services/abstract.rule.service';
import { AbstractRuleConditionService } from './services/abstract.rule-condition.service';
import { AbstractRuleFieldService } from './services/abstract.rule-field.service';
import { AbstractRuleTypeService } from './services/abstract.rule-type.service';
import { AbstractGeneralService } from './services/abstract.general.service';
import { RuleService } from './services/rule.service';
import { RuleConditionService } from './services/rule-condition.service';
import { RuleFieldService } from './services/rule-field.service';
import { RuleTypeService } from './services/rule-type.service';
import { GeneralService } from './services/general.service';
import { MockRuleService } from './services/mock.rule.service';
import { MockRuleConditionService } from './services/mock.rule-condition.service';
import { MockRuleTypeService } from './services/mock.rule-type.service';
import { MockGeneralService } from './services/mock.general.service';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Rules1Component } from './components/rule-engine/rules/rules1.component';
import { Rules2Component } from './components/rule-engine/rules/rules2.component';
import { Rules1DetailsComponent } from './components/rule-engine/rules/rules1.details.component';
import { Rules2DetailsComponent } from './components/rule-engine/rules/rules2.details.component';
import { RuleFieldsComponent } from './components/rule-engine/rule-fields/rule-fields.component';
import { RuleGroupsComponent } from './components/rule-engine/rule-groups/rule-groups.component';
import { RuleResultEntityComponent } from './components-old/rule-result-entities/rule-result-entities.component';
import { RuleResultEntityFieldsComponent } from './components/rule-engine/rule-result-entity-fields/rule-result-entity-fields.component';
import { RuleBuiltInFunctionsComponent } from './components/rule-engine/rule-built-in-functions/rule-built-in-functions.component';
import { RuleBuiltInFunctionParamsComponent } from './components/rule-engine/rule-built-in-functions/rule-built-in-function-params.component';
import { RuleTypeComponent } from './components-old/rule-types/rule-types.component';
import { AlertComponent } from './components/alert/alert.component';
import { ApiRuleAssociationComponent } from './components-old/api-rule-associations/api-rule-associations.component';
import { CboFinancialInstitutionComponent } from './components-old/cbo-financial-institution/cbo-financial-institution.component';
import { CboPaymentServiceDirectoryComponent } from './components-old/cbo-payment-service-directory/cbo-payment-service-directory.component';
import { CboMessageTypeComponent } from './components-old/cbo-message-types/cbo-message-types.component';
import { CboPaymentServicesFiComponent } from './components-old/cbo-payment-servicefi/cbo-payment-servicefi.component';
import { CboRmaDynamicComponent } from './components/payments/cbo-rma.component';
import { CboCutOffComponent } from './components-old/cbo-cut-offs/cbo-cut-offs.component';
import { CboCorrespondentComponent } from './components-old/cbo-correspondent/cbo-correspondent.component';
import { CboPaymentServiceComponent } from './components-old/cbo-payment-service/cbo-payment-service.component';
import { CboCurrenciesFiComponent } from './components-old/cbo-currenciesfi/cbo-currenciesfi.component';
import { CboCurrenciesFiDynamicComponent } from './components/payments/cbo-currenciesfi.component';
import { CboFinancialInstitutionDynamicComponent } from './components/payments/cbo-financial-institution.component';
import { CboPaymentServiceDirectoryDynamicComponent } from './components/payments/cbo-payment-service-directory.component';
import { CboPaymentServiceDynamicComponent } from './components/payments/cbo-payment-service.component';
import { CboCutOffDynamicComponent } from './components/payments/cbo-cut-offs.component';
import { CboPaymentServicesFiDynamicComponent } from './components/payments/cbo-payment-servicefi.component';
import { ApiRuleAssociationsDynamicComponent } from './components/rule-engine/api-rule-associations.component';
import { CboMessageTypesDynamicComponent } from './components/payments/cbo-message-types.component';
import { RuleTypeDynamicComponent } from './components/rule-engine/rule-types.component';
import { RuleResultEntityDynamicComponent } from './components/rule-engine/rule-result-entities.component';
import { RuleFieldsDynamicComponent } from './components/rule-engine/rule-fields-tree.component';
import { RuleGroupsDetailComponent } from './components/rule-engine/rule-groups/rule-groups-detail.component';
import { RuleResultEntityFieldsDynamicComponent } from './components/rule-engine/rule-result-entity-fields-tree.component';
import { RuleGroupActionModalComponent } from './components/rule-engine/rule-groups/rule-group-action-modal.component';

const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '', component: UniRulesLibComponent, children: [
            { path: 'rulegroups', component: RuleGroupsComponent },
            { path: 'rules', component: Rules1Component },
            { path: 'rules2', component: Rules2Component },
            { path: 'ruletypes', component: RuleTypeComponent },
            { path: 'rulefields', component: RuleFieldsComponent },
            { path: 'rulebuiltinfunctions', component: RuleBuiltInFunctionsComponent },
            { path: 'ruleresultentities', component: RuleResultEntityComponent },
            { path: 'ruleresultentityfields', component: RuleResultEntityFieldsComponent },
            { path: 'apiruleassociations', component: ApiRuleAssociationComponent },
            { path: 'cbofinancialinstitution', component: CboFinancialInstitutionComponent },
            { path: 'cbopaymentservicedirectory', component: CboPaymentServiceDirectoryComponent },
            { path: 'cbopaymentservicesfi', component: CboPaymentServicesFiComponent },
            { path: 'cbomessagetypes', component: CboMessageTypeComponent },
            { path: 'cbormas', component: CboRmaDynamicComponent },
            { path: 'cbocutoffs', component: CboCutOffComponent },
            { path: 'cbocorrespondents', component: CboCorrespondentComponent },
            { path: 'cbopaymentservices', component: CboPaymentServiceComponent },
            { path: 'cbocurrenciesfi', component: CboCurrenciesFiComponent },
            { path: 'ruletypesdynamic', component: RuleTypeDynamicComponent },
            { path: 'cbofinancialinstitutionsdynamic', component: CboFinancialInstitutionDynamicComponent },
            { path: 'cbopaymentservicedirectoriesdynamic', component: CboPaymentServiceDirectoryDynamicComponent },
            { path: 'cbocorrespondentsdynamic', component: CboCorrespodentDynamicComponent },
            { path: 'cbopaymentservicesdynamic', component: CboPaymentServiceDynamicComponent },
            { path: 'cbocurrenciesfidynamic', component: CboCurrenciesFiDynamicComponent },
            { path: 'cbocutoffsdynamic', component: CboCutOffDynamicComponent },
            { path: 'cbopaymentservicesfidynamic', component: CboPaymentServicesFiDynamicComponent },
            { path: 'cbormasdynamic', component: CboRmaDynamicComponent },
            { path: 'cbomessagetypesdynamic', component: CboMessageTypeComponent },
            { path: 'apiruleassociationsdynamic', component: ApiRuleAssociationsDynamicComponent },
            { path: 'ruleresultentitiesdynamic', component: RuleResultEntityDynamicComponent },
            { path: 'rulefieldsdymamic', component: RuleFieldsDynamicComponent },
            { path: 'ruleresultentityfieldsdynamic', component: RuleResultEntityFieldsDynamicComponent }
        ]
    }
];

const ApiProviders = [
    { provide: AbstractRuleService, useClass: RuleService },
    { provide: AbstractRuleConditionService, useClass: RuleConditionService },
    { provide: AbstractRuleFieldService, useClass: RuleFieldService },
    { provide: AbstractRuleTypeService, useClass: RuleTypeService },
    { provide: AbstractGeneralService, useClass: GeneralService }
];
const MockProviders = [
    { provide: AbstractRuleService, useClass: MockRuleService },
    { provide: AbstractRuleConditionService, useClass: MockRuleConditionService },
    { provide: AbstractRuleTypeService, useClass: MockRuleTypeService },
    { provide: AbstractGeneralService, useClass: MockGeneralService }
];
function initializeApp(generalService: AbstractGeneralService) {
    console.log("initializeApp");
    return () => generalService.init();
}
const InitProvider = { provide: APP_INITIALIZER, useFactory: initializeApp, deps: [GeneralService], multi: true, }

// @dynamic
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        UniRulesLibComponent,
        Rules1Component,
        Rules2Component,
        Rules1DetailsComponent,
        Rules2DetailsComponent,
        RuleFieldsComponent,
        RuleGroupsComponent,
        RuleResultEntityComponent,
        RuleResultEntityFieldsComponent,
        RuleBuiltInFunctionsComponent,
        RuleBuiltInFunctionParamsComponent,
        RuleTypeComponent,
        AlertComponent,
        ApiRuleAssociationComponent,
        CboFinancialInstitutionComponent,
        CboPaymentServiceDirectoryComponent,
        CboMessageTypeComponent,
        CboPaymentServicesFiComponent,
        CboRmaDynamicComponent,
        CboCutOffComponent,
        CboCorrespondentComponent,
        CboPaymentServiceComponent,
        CboCurrenciesFiComponent,
        CboCurrenciesFiDynamicComponent,
        CboCorrespodentDynamicComponent,
        CboFinancialInstitutionDynamicComponent,
        CboPaymentServiceDirectoryDynamicComponent,
        CboPaymentServiceDynamicComponent,
        CboCutOffDynamicComponent,
        CboPaymentServicesFiDynamicComponent,
        ApiRuleAssociationsDynamicComponent,
        CboMessageTypesDynamicComponent,
        RuleTypeDynamicComponent,
        RuleResultEntityDynamicComponent,
        RuleFieldsDynamicComponent,
        RuleGroupsDetailComponent,
        RuleResultEntityFieldsDynamicComponent,
        RuleGroupActionModalComponent
        ],
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forChild(routes),
        CommonModule, /* for *ngIf */

        DxDataGridModule,
        DxButtonModule,
        DxSelectBoxModule,
        DxTemplateModule,
        DxDateBoxModule,
        DxTreeListModule,
        DxListModule,
        DxTextBoxModule,
        DxFormModule,
        DxTextAreaModule,
        DxCheckBoxModule,
        DxFileUploaderModule,
        DxNumberBoxModule,
        DxPopupModule,
        DxTagBoxModule,
        DxPieChartModule,
        DxChartModule,
    ],
    exports: [
        UniRulesLibComponent,
    ],
    providers: [
        ...ApiProviders,
        // ...MockProviders,
        InitProvider,
    ],
})
export class UniRulesLibModule { }

app-routing.module.ts:
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'uni-rules', loadChildren: () => import(`uni-rules-lib`).then(m => m.UniRulesLibModule)}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }

app.module.ts:
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';  
import { DxDrawerModule, DxListModule, DxPopupModule, DxToolbarModule, DxTreeViewModule } from 'devextreme-angular';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment'
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { SettingsComponent } from '../components/settings/settings.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    SettingsComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    DxDrawerModule,
    DxListModule,
    DxPopupModule,
    DxToolbarModule,
    DxTreeViewModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [
    { provide: 'environment', useValue: environment }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }


The initializeApp is depend on GeneralService, but you declare it with function initializeApp(generalService: AbstractGeneralService). Meanwhile, have you tried adding InitProvider into the root app module AppModule, instead of UniRulesLibModule? Because you are lazy-loading this module.

I changed initializeApp to use GeneralService instead of AbstractGeneralService:
function initializeApp(generalService: GeneralService) {
 console.log("initializeApp");
 return () => generalService.init();
}

However it is still not called.
I do not want to add InitProvider to AppModule, because this is library specific. I do not want everyone using the library, having to add InitProvider in the AppModule.

Hmmm, I don't think that is how APP_INITIALIZER works when it is in the lazy-loaded module. The provided functions are injected at application startup and executed during app initialization.. Correct me if I'm wrong. So from what I understand here, you want the APP_INITIALIZER function execute when the module is loaded.

Yes, exactly, APP_INITIALIZER should execute when the library is used for the first time.

As mentioned in the comment, the APP_INITIALIZER function/factory provider is only executed during the app startup. Hence, APP_INITIALIZER is not working in your scenario.
What you try to achieve is the function to be called immediately when the module is loaded, you can call the function in the module's constructor.
export class UniRulesLibModule {
  constructor(private service: GeneralService) {
    initializeApp(service)();
  }
}

Unsure how is the implementation of your GeneralService, if you are trying to provide the value in your service through subscription from the component, you should work with BehaviorSubject. Below is the sample service that I built:
export class GeneralService {
  private http = inject(HttpClient);

  private _config: BehaviorSubject<any | null> = new BehaviorSubject(null);
  private _user: any;

  public getConfigUrl(key: string): Observable<any> {
    return this._config
      .asObservable()
      .pipe(map((x: any) => x.urls[key] as string));
  }

  public init(): Promise<any> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      console.log('Resolve promise load()');

      this._config.next({
        urls: {
          test: 'www.test.com',
        },
      });

      resolve(true);
    });
  }
}

Demo @ StackBlitz

I added the constructor to UniRulesLibModule:
export class UniRulesLibModule {
 constructor(private service: AbstractGeneralService) {
   initializeApp(service);
 }
  }

initializeApp calls generalService.init() which calls a REST API which returns an Observable with the lookup values of the combo-boxes. The problem is, that the Observable is resolved after initializing the combo-boxes, and therefore, the combo-boxes are without list of values.
Is there a way to make the Observable resolve immediately?
